# Safely interrupt C++11 blocking operation

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, condition-variable

I have a `std::thread` that uses Boost's asio to read from a serial port:

```
std::atomic<bool> quit(false);

void serialThread()
{
    try
    {
        asio::io_service io;
        asio::serial_port port(io);

        port.open("COM9"); // Yeay no port enumeration support!

        port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(9600));

        while (!quit)
        {
            asio::streambuf buf;
            asio::read_until(port, buf, "\n");

            auto it = asio::buffers_begin(buf.data());
            string line(it, it + buf.size());

            doStuffWithLine(line);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception e)
    {
        cout << "Serial thread error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}

void SetupSignals()
{
    // Arrange it so that `quit = true;` happens when Ctrl-C is pressed.
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SetupSignals();

    thread st(serialThread);

    st.join();

    return 0;
}
```

When I press Ctrl-C I want to ***cleanly*** exit the thread, so that all destructors are called appropriately (some drivers on Windows hate it if you don't close their resources properly).

Unfortunately as you can see, the current code blocks in `read_until()` so when you press Ctrl-C nothing will happen until a new line of text is received.

One solution is to use polling, something like this:

```
asio::async_read_until(port, buf, "\n", ...);
while (!quit)
    io.poll();
```

But I'd rather not use polling. It is pretty inelegant. The only solution I can currently see is to have a `std::condition_variable quitOrIoFinished` that is triggered either when `quit` is set to true, or when the read finishes. But I didn't write asio so I can't give it a condition variable to wait on.

Is there any clean sane solution? In Go I would just use a `select` to wait on multiple channels, where one of them is a quit channel. I can't see a similar solution in C++ though.

Comment: Pretty sure there is a way to specify a timeout to `asio::read_until`. Set that timeout to maybe 200ms and check if you should exit before trying again.

Comment: Yeah that's just less agressive polling though... I'd like a non-polling solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `asio::signal_set` to await the INT signal (control-C tends to send interrupt).

When it arrives, simply call `cancel()` on your IO objects with pending asynchronous operations. They will return with `error_code` equal to `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.

Now, if you have a `io_service::work` object, destruct it and the all threads running `io_service::run()` will return, so you can join them.

**Note** Take care of synchronizing access to your IO objects (e.g. when you invoke `cancel()` on them) because these objects are not thread-safe, unlike `io_service` and `strand`.

Comment: this answer is unsafe: calling cancel() or anything ASIO from a signal handler is *undefined behaviour*. You may only call signal handler safe functions which is a very limited subset, most people signal a semaphore or write a byte to a pipe to wake a thread to handle the signal. I'd suggest not varying from that idiom.

Comment: @NiallDouglas Nowhere in my answer did I suggest dealing with raw signal handlers. That's an ASIO detail

Comment: Yep you're right. Blame the lack of coffee before that reply, sorry. I would mention though that I don't believe signal_set is portable, Windows doesn't use signals for example, to catch Ctrl-C there you install a console control handler.